# Start external activity to display Maps

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-activity, maps

This is whats up.  I want to start an external activity to display geo-coordinates, rather than implement Google Maps inside my application.  Currently I have too much on hand, and I don't want to go through the hassle of implementing a map.  Therefore, would it be possible to pass the parameters to the external maps activity, similar to what we do with text message, phone call, camera, etc.?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can do that with this command:

```
private void openMapGeo(String latitude, String longitude) {
    Intent intent2 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("geo:" + latitude + ","
            + longitude + "?z=17&q=" + latitude + "," + longitude));
    // z stands for zoom level
    // replace the q with a search string works too. Example:
    // intent2 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
    // Uri.parse("geo:0,0?q=Tokyo"));
    startActivity(intent2);
}
```

Another way is to use the maps website url. This will ask the user if he wants to open the maps application (if installed) or the browser:

```
private void openMapUrl(String latitude, String longitude) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
            Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/?q=" + latitude + "," + longitude));
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Some other examples here: https://github.com/pboos/GoogleMapExamples (look at the Presentation.pdf file in there)

---

EDIT:

To use both above depending on the fact if the google maps application is installed do this (both above functions need to exist as well):

```
private void openMap(String latitude, String longitude) {
    try {
       ApplicationInfo info = getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo("com.google.android.apps.maps", 0 );
        openMapGeo(latitude, longitude);
    } catch(PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        openMapUrl(latitude, longitude);
    }
}
```

Comment: What if Google Maps is not installed on the phone?

Comment: I think Android mobile is having Google map as an in-built application. Isn't it?

Comment: @Patrick: Just a question out of curiosity. What does "z=17" means here?

Comment: z=17 is the zoom level. if the app is not installed, use openMapUrl above. You can check if the maps applications is installed by using the PackageManager (getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo("com.google.android.apps.maps", 0 );) - check for exception ;-)

Comment: added code in the post to show how to check if maps app is installed

Comment: Just launch a URL intent that starts with `http://maps.google.com/...` If google maps is installed in the phone, it will prompt the user asking them whether they want to open the URL in a browser or in Google Maps app. All you have to do in dynamically create the google maps url.

Comment: @Ali true, that is the easiest way. As explained below the openMapUrl function, it does exactly what you said.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually use the maps web application by going to the browser and going to the google map's website and then running whatever kind of query you want. Look at the api for maps.